# Running stored procedure remotely for non IT user

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

We have a SQL server that we are using for our data warehouse.
We want to give a department the ability to update the data when they want (and not just on schedule).

Was is the best way to do this? We have a SP that we are thinking of calling from a batch script, but is there a more elegant way?

The data will eventually go into Palo Jedox for BI.

Comment: You could wrap it in a Reporting Services report. That way you can render some feedback for the user as well.

Answer (score 2):

I do this sort of thing by writing a ColdFusion web page that the user can run.  It could also be done with .net, php, java, etc.

Comment: Yep- was thinking this. I've had another thought though. Our ERP has a "Task Maintenance" section where we can setup jobs that call PL/SQL packages. I could create a linked server to the SQL server and execute it like that possibly.

Answer (score 1):

Do not give users the ability to change the tables directly.

Instead, create one or more stored procedures to do the updates/inserts/deletes that you want to do.  If it is one record, you can just pass in the values as arguments.  If it is a bunch of records, you need a mechanism to transfer larger data into the database -- either reading from a text file or putting it into a table in the database some way.

Be sure the stored procedure has the same owner as the underlying tables.  Using owner chaining, the stored procedure will be able to make changes to the tables.  At no time can a user make a change to the data directly, only through the stored procedure.

Then, log, log, log everything that gets done.  You want to know every time this stored procedure is called to change the data.